# Login loop with NVIDIA 440 driver on Ubuntu 18.04 (after installing pylon)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

I have a huge problem with NVidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04.

I use two graphics cards, Nvidia Quadro K4200 and GTX 750 Ti. Both screens are connected to K4200 via DVI and DP and I use GTX 750 Ti for CUDA stuff.

I installed [pylon 5.2.0 deb package](https://www.baslerweb.com/en/sales-support/downloads/software-downloads/) and after reboot one of the screens stopped working. Moreover, nvidia-smi stopped working as well:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.
```

"Nvidia X Server settings" was displaying an empty window.

### Attempt 1: reinstall drivers

I deleted all the nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
```

And installed the latest driver (440) that supports both of my graphic cards:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

Now, once I get to the login screen and enter the password, the system gets stuck on the purple boot screen.

I can switch to a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F5), log in there and verify that nvidia-smi works. However, once I try to restart gdm

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm.service
```

I get back to infinite login loop in GUI.

### Attempt 2: xorg.conf

I found the same issue being discussed [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1043405/linux/ubuntu-18-04-headless_390-intel-igpu-after-prime-select-intel-lost-contact-to-geforce-1050ti/post/5293003/#5293003).
After following the steps and setting driver to *modesetting* in */etc/X11/xorg.conf*

```
    Section "Device"
        Identifier     "GK104GL"
        Driver         "modesetting"
        BusID          "PCI:0:5:0"
    EndSection
```

I can login, nvidia-smi works as expected, however, the mouse pointer reacts with 1-2s delay.

### More information

With the Nvidia drivers uninstalled the system works, I can login, both screens are functional. Obviously, I can not use nvidia-smi and CUDA.

Once I switch from nvidia to intel and reboot

```
sudo prime-select intel
sudo reboot now
```

I can login, but only 1 screen works.

I would be really thankful if someone would help me to return the system to the state, where it's working again with the nvidia driver.

### Update:

Booting with `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` parameter does not help.
Driver 430.64 - also infinite login loop.

I made a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 (same kernek 5.3.0-28) on a new SSD on the same PC. Then installed nvidia driver as described above and everything works as expected.

This means the issue is not with BIOS or kernel flags. What could it be?

### Update 2:

I checked */var/log/Xorg.0.log* there are two errors:

```
[7.219] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[7.219] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[7.220] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching cofig section
```

This errors are not present in the log of the new fresh functioning Ubuntu install.

Comment: What Kernel version do you use? I had similar problem switching to 19.10, it recognized only Intel VGA since the newer driver didn't work with the older Kernel 4.15.0

Comment: Kernel 5.3.0-28. Should be fine I guess?